# Android Phonegap app doesn't resume

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

When using PhoneGap 3.0 to build apps for Android, they don't resume after being minimized.

I've tested on both an S2 and S4, and my app restarts from the beginning every time.

1. Start the app
2. Press the home-button
3. Press the app icon on home screen

= Result: App restarts from the beginning

Is there a way to make it resume where the user left off, like it would in iOs?

(exit-on-suspend is set to false in config.xml)